# How to mock variables inside redux saga generator functions?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-redux, redux-saga

how can I test the saga below?

```
export function* getSnapShotFromUserAuth(userAuth, additionalData) {
  try {
    const userRef = yield call(
      createUserProfileDocument,
      userAuth,
      additionalData
    );
    const userSnapshot = yield userRef.get();
    yield put(signInSuccess({ id: userSnapshot.id, ...userSnapshot.data() }));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(signInFailure(error));
  }
}
```

I was only able to get it working up until the first line:

```
describe("getSnapShotFromUserAuth", () => {
  const mockUserAuth = {};
  const mockAdditionalData = {};
  const generator = getSnapShotFromUserAuth(mockUserAuth, mockAdditionalData);

  it("should get snapshot from user auth", () => {
    expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(
      call(createUserProfileDocument, mockUserAuth, mockAdditionalData)
    );
  });
});
```

How can I verify the next line? `const userSnapshot = yield userRef.get();`

I keep getting error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` when calling trying to test the next line as it cannot find `userRef`. Is there a way to be able to mock the next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer -

```
it("should check for signInSuccess", () => {
    const myMock = jest.fn();
    let userRef = {
      get: myMock.mockReturnValue({
        id: 1,
        data: () => {},
      }),
    };

    let userSnapshot = {
      id: 1,
      data: () => {},
    };
    generator.next(userRef);

    expect(generator.next(userSnapshot).value).toEqual(
      put(signInSuccess({ id: userSnapshot.id, ...userSnapshot.data() }))
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can dictate what the result of the `yield` is by what you pass in when you call `next()`. So for example, after doing the first `generator.next`, you can do:

```
const mockUserRef = {
  get: jest.fn();
}
expect(generator.next(mockUserRef).value).toEqual(/* whatever */);
```

Comment: Tried it this way(see below) and now getting an error 
```Expected: {"data": [Function data], "id": 1}
    Received: serializes to the same string```


```let userRef = {
      get: () => {
        return {
          id: 1,
          data: () => {},
        };
      },
    };

    let expected = {
      id: 1,
      data: () => {},
    };

    expect(generator.next(userRef).value).toEqual(expected);```

Comment: I figured out the above issue. Had to call `generator.next(userRef);` and then do the check on the next yield. Thanks for your help.